# MSAccess JET showplan.out strange execution order

Tags: ms-access, vb6, jet

Does anybody know why JET showplan is giving me first a sort on the table and only afterwards the outer join? This seems to be indicating it reads the entire Orderline table?

```
01) Restrict rows of table Order
      using rushmore
      for expression "Order.OrderType ='Web'"
      then test expression "Order.OrderDate>=#1-1-2014# And Order.OrderDate <=#2-9-2014#"
02) Sort table 'Orderline'
03) Outer Join result of '01)' to result of '02)'
      using temporary index
      join expression "Order.OrderID=Orderline.OrderID"
```

Thanks for any insights to JET showplan.out logging.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason would be if there is no index for 'Orderline.OrderID'? IF that field is indexd, then what volume of records are in each of those tables? For example, if there are lots fewer rows in OrderLine than in Orders...
Also, see: http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Showplanout-Analysis-t1998635.html&p=2321490